# it seems to that PayPal's Smart Payment Buttons code 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb' does not support IPv6

Tags: paypal

i am integrating paypal into my mobile apps, but something wrong, when i add the smart payment button code 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' to my H5 website, when app's network environment is only ipv6，it can't access to 'www.paypal.com/sdk/js', but ipv4 it works. Does it means that paypal does not support ipv6?

i have tried my app in ipv6 or ipv4 environment to test this issue.

```
<script>
    if(PAY_ENV === "development") document.write("<script src='https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AR80ByVv-jgJtWSnMqdQQNWt3YyzCfZzUbhYYkoFYev2QXTTOSjp_cgxxxxxx'><\/script>");
    else document.write("<script src='https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AZzjVPUB7szeq393RAR5TjsgU_V2Lcj1PpYrnl9WyLTTuGdfvKZLCGk8AOZvajLUOD3GXxxxxxx'><\/script>");
</script>
```

Comment: It means that *your app*, or more likey the entire device, can't access an IPv4 server out of an IPV6-only environment.

Comment: yes,it seems that www.paypal.com does not support ipv6.It's a pity.